# Fail to make hector_gazebo_thermal_camera

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build, msg, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I am building hector_quadrotor(http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) package. It needs another package named hector_gazebo_thermal_camera(inside http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo).

Using catkin_make, the building is **successful** on **X86**-Ubuntu14.04-Indigo, but **failed** on **ARMv7l**-Ubuntu14.04-Indigo. The error message is showed below:

```
[ 13%] Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/GazeboRosThermalCamera.cfg: /home/chris/ros_ws/devel/include/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/GazeboRosThermalCameraConfig.h /home/chris/ros_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/cfg/GazeboRosThermalCameraConfig.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/chris/ros_ws/src/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/cfg/GazeboRosThermalCamera.cfg", line 5, in <module>
    from driver_base.msg import SensorLevels
ImportError: No module named msg
make[2]: *** [/home/chris/ros_ws/devel/include/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/GazeboRosThermalCameraConfig.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_thermal_camera_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

P.S. It is hard to install dependencies into ARM platform. Because most of them don't provide the ARM versions. I built a lot of dependencies from source. Will this error is leaded by the dependency mistaking installed?

Thank you for helping me out!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229181/fail-to-make-hector_gazebo_thermal_camera/) by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is missing the `driver_base` package [see here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/driver_common/tree/indigo-devel/driver_base).

Have you installed this?

If you have cloned but not yet built this package (or if they are in the same ROS workspace), it might also be that the messages are not yet created due to a not properly configured `CMakeLists.txt`.
Try installing the `driver_base` package first.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2016-03-16**:
Thank you for your reply!
I have download the driver_base source and placed it inside the ROS workspace.
There has been a command "find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS nodelet image_transport dynamic_reconfigure **driver_base** gazebo_plugins)" in the CMakeLists of hector_gazebo_thermal_camera

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2016-03-16**:
I use "catkin_make --pkg driver_base" to pre-build the pkg. But it doesn't work

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-16**:
the error actually states that there is the Python `msg` module in `base_driver` missing. This can e.g. happen, when the packages are not built in the correct order. Can you check if `/home/chris/ros_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` contains the respective `msg` in the `base_driver` folder?

**Comment by [pcler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20519/pcler/) on 2016-03-16**:
Yes, I can find the relative .py file of the message now. Now it seems that the pre-build of driver_base succeeded! Thank you so much!